# Getting Security Authentication Exception in Kibana Installation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have installed ElasticSearch8.6.2 successfully and able to see the below information in http://localhost:9200/

```
{
  "name" : "*******",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "********",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.6.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "zip",
    "build_hash" : "*******",
    "build_date" : "2023-02-13T09:35:20.314882762Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.4.2",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

After this, I tried to install Kibana 8.6.2 and got the below error.

`Kibana server is not ready yet.`

```
[2023-04-01T12:48:04.719+05:30][ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: missing authentication credentials for REST request [/_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.version%2Cnodes.*.http.publish_address%2Cnodes.*.ip]
```

Kibana.yml and command-prompt logs are attached [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Z-tJ1Y4piMzll0S_mdDbH00nzmc5azp_?usp=sharing) for reference.

Note: I have generated a random password for the `kibana_system` user and updated the same in `kibana.yml` file.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Isn't everything commented out in your kibana.yml? But adding the `kibana_system` user with the right credentials is the correct way to connect. Also make sure to use HTTPS if you have configured it (which would happen by default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a failure reason. I opened the **Command prompt** in **Admin rights** and ran the **ElasticSearch.bat** file, that's why the password for the elastic user and service token was not created. I fixed it myself.